# Groupby evaulating locally for Entity Framework Core 2.1.4 inside Azure Function version 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, entity-framework-core-2.1

Microsoft says that the Entity Framework Core 2.1 generates a `GROUPBY` statement to the server. I have an Azure Function using the Entity Framework Core 2.1.4 but still got:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Sum()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

My query is:

```
var q = await db.TblRainGauging5minutes
    .Where(x => x.G_ID == 1)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.G_ID })
    .Select(g => new {
        Id = g.Key.G_ID,
        Total = g.Sum(v => v.R_Value ?? 0),
        Rows = g.Count()
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Here's my project setting:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AzureFunctions.Autofac" Version="3.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is anything wrong in my setting or code? Maybe it just doesn't work in Azure function 2? I have changed the target framework from `netstandard2.0` to `netcoreapp2.1.4` and I still get the problem.

Comment: What if you try with just `.GroupBy(x => x.G_ID)`

Comment: @Camilo I am grouping by 2 columns, just to make it simple here.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem with pure .NetCore project, so Azure Function is not the issue. The real problem may be the sql server. When I target sql server 2012, I can always get the problem; but when I target sql server 2016, the GROUP BY statement shows and I don't see the warning anymore. SQL profiler shows the same result.

Comment: I have spent hours to further test this and found out that the Sum statement is the real problem. Even against Sql server 2012, it doesn't show the warning after taking out the Sum statement. I have tried sum on int field too. Hopefully someone can verify this and thus save others hours trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: The test was performed in a .netcore web app, TargetFramework=netcoreapp2.2, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 2.2, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2